# Lookback lexer member in antlr4

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4, lexer, ambiguous

is there a way to "fake" a lookback in Antlr4 ? 
I want to resolve some ambiguity according to the token right before where I am.

**EDIT**

```
read: STAR text STAR text STAR text
| STAR text STAR KEY_WORD STAR text

text: STR +;

@lexer::members {
  private boolean checkAhead(int maxAmountOfCharacters, String pattern) {
    final Interval ahead = new Interval(this._tokenStartCharIndex, this._tokenStartCharIndex + maxAmountOfCharacters - 1);
    return this._input.getText(ahead).matches(pattern);
  }

KEY_WORD: LETTER LETTER LETTER LETTER LETTER ;
STAR :'*';

STR: {( !checkAhead(6, "([A-Z]){5}[*](\\D|$)") }?
    (
        LETTER
        | DIGIT
    )+
;
```

I want the input to be read as KEY_WORD only if it's STAR KEY_WORD STAR
for now if the last word of a text is [A-Z]{5}  it's matched to KEY_WORD

Comment: please, share part of rour grammar and a simple example scenario of your problem

Comment: sorry, question and example changed

Comment: Need to provide sample input marked with expected results. Not clear what you are asking for from your description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative offset in the lookahead functions LA() and LT() (LA gives you just the token type, while LT gives you the entire token). **Note:** LA(0) is not defined, but you can use LA(-1), LA(-2), LT(5) etc.

**Another note:** looking back further than one step works only with buffered token streams. Unbuffered streams only cache a single token (the previous one).

The TokenStream class (from which your `this._input` instance is derived) defines the LT() function. LA() is available in the IntStream class (which is the ancestor for any character input stream, like CharStream or ANTLRInputStream.

Comment: is the LT() in antlr 4 ? I can't use it, at least from my lexer file can you please add a small example? thanks

Comment: Added a bit more info where to find LA + LT.

Comment: I was trying to access the LT in the Lexer file, that's why I couldn't use it first. Thanks !

Comment: @JCCNoobie, please accept my answer if it helped you (the check under the voting arrows).